# Strange lighting/shadows in Unreal Engine game (shadow suddenly gets darker or lighter)

Tags: unreal-4, lighting, unreal

[image]

As the title suggests. I have made a level for Unreal Engine. It uses `RectLights` in the ceiling without any directional lighting. There is a Lightmass Importance Volume and Post Processing.

I show GIF animation to show the problem, but similar stuff happens all over the maps I have made.

Is this a problem from the Light, the Level Geometry or something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , make sure that you have made your rect light to static mesh , the try to change the position of light and again replace it at the position and then make sure you have builded the lighting .

Comment: Thanks I have been meaning to go back to this project, I'll try this out soon and let you know if it works.